# multiple AJAX calls issue with index

Tags: javascript, ajax, closures

I have a specific code architecture and the request is to execute AJAX calls in a loop. I am getting a problem where the index of a loop is always its maximum value due to asynchronous calls that are being made in the loop. Please let me know what would be a proper way to implement this closure so that the calls could be made for each array value.

```
for (ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) {                                
    ImgViewerNS.init.getJson(ur1mgfeed_array[ii],
        function (data){                                          
            if (data.d.__count > 0) {
                 //
                 //
            }
        },
        ImgViewerNS.init.logError)
 }
 .
 .
 .
 getJson: function (endpointUri, success, error) {
     $.ajax({
         url: endpointUri,
         type: "GET",
         processData: false,
         contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
         headers: {
             "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
         },
         success: success,
         error: error
      });
}
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `for` loop, use `let` to define `ii` variable so that it will have block-level scope and not function level scope.

```
for (let ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) {                                
...rest of your code...
```

This problem is occurring because you are using `async` functions inside a `for` loop, `for` loop or any JavaScript code doesn't wait for execution `async` method and by the time that `async` method reaches to call stack, the closure references keep the latest values.

You can refer this article to know more about it - https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-closures-with-confidence-85cd1f841a6b

Comment: Your solution works in Chrome , in IE I am getting 'Expected ';'' in debugger at the loop- do you know why?

Comment: Can you double check whether you have added `;` correctly in for loop syntax?

Comment: It is the exact same code for both browsers    for (let ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {..

Comment: I have also tried for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                  let ii =j;     ….}                                                                      but I get the same error . I see on the web that 'let' is not working well with IE, is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
async function makeCall() {
  for (let ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) {
    await ImgViewerNS.init.getJson(ur1mgfeed_array[ii],
      function(data) {
        if (data.d.__count > 0) {
          //
          //
        }
      },
      ImgViewerNS.init.logError)
  }
```